# Shell Scripting - How to mock some results based on an input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I have a small scripts which verifies some conditions on a database server. I want to mock failures on all of those conditions to test the script, so I added the following line:

```
./print_results ${VAR1} ${VAR2} ... ${VARN}
```

If any of the variables has a value different than ZERO it because it failed.

so just for testing purpouses I added the line:

```
VAR1=1 ; VAR2=1 ; ... ; VARN=1
```

But I need to edit the file every time I want to replace the real results with the fake ones.

What's wrong with this?

```
[! -z $1 ] && [ "$1" == "Y"] && { echo "Debugging is ACTIVE" ; VAR1=1 ; ... ; VAR2=1 ; }
```

I want to have the `VAR1..N = 1` after passing that line.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error that says something like: `[! command not found`?

Comment: You need white space surrounding all `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a space between the "Y" and the ]. The non-zero test is pointless, but also requires a space between the [ and the !.

```
[ "$1" == "Y" ] && { echo "Debugging is ACTIVE" ; VAR1=1 ; ... ; VAR2=1 ; }
```

Also did you consider just writing this as an if...fi block?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `[` is a command, but `[!` is not.  It is probably cleaner to write your code:

```
test "{$1}" == Y && { echo "Debugging is ACTIVE"; VAR1=1 VAR2=1 ...; }
```

No need for semi-colons between the variable assignments, but they don't hurt.

This is one of the warts of sh.  For some reason, it was thought to be a good idea to use the symbol `[` for a command and pass it `]` as an argument, trying to mimic braces in the language.  Unfortunately, this leads to a great deal of confusion similar to that demonstrated in this question.  It is far better to avoid `[` completely and always spell it `test`.  These two are functionally identical (except that the `[` command must have `]` as the final argument), and using `test` is much cleaner.  (Would you expect `test!` to work?, or would you recognize that it needs to be written as `! test`?)

Answer (score 0):

`bash` provides a way to supply default values for parameters that aren't otherwise set. Presumably, your code has lines like

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
VAR3=$3
```

Replace them with

```
VAR1=${1-1}
VAR2=${2-1}
VAR3=${3-1}
```

If `$1` is unset, for instance, `VAR1` will be assigned the value of 1 instead of the value of `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for answering on that but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering on that but this doesn't solve my problem. VAR1, ... N contain the results from some verifications I performed and they will always got set, so the parameter expansion won't be ever used.